# Do I need to manage DB connection pools in Play Framework, or does Play do it for me?

Tags: mysql, playframework, connection-pooling, playframework-1.x

Do I need to obtain a context and DataSource in every method that reads/writes to the DB? (Sample below) Or does `Play.db.DB`'s getConnection() method handle the pool transparently?

```
    public void saveResponse() {
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx
                .lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDB");

        conn = ds.getConnection();

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("SOME SQL QUERY");

        stmt.close();
        stmt = null;

        conn.close();
        conn = null;

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play can manage that for you.

But why don't you use Play's JPA persistence?
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/jpa

That would be even more transparent than getting connections.